# Store views are not displaying in Admin portal product details page

Tags: magento2.2.4

Store views are there if I will go to Stores >> All Stores

But If I go to any product details page and the scope drop-down only shows the default store view.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the product and go to the Websites tab and add the product into the Website that you want custom pricing on.

Then it will be appear in the dropdown.

Comment: Thanks Ritesh. Worked.

Comment: @SuchismitaP Can please accept to this answer or vote this